# Ruby on Rails - Heroku problems & User sign-in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

First post here on SO. I am relatively new to Ruby on Rails and I have been reading through Michael Hartl's book, "Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Learn by Example". However, I have the following problems when running my application that I would be gracious to get solved.

1) When trying to run my application in 'production' mode, I have updated the file 'config/environments.rb' as follows:

```
    # force Rails into production mode when
    # you don't control web/app server and can't set it the proper way
    ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

However, when I run the application, I can still see the debugger facility present from the file 'app/views/layouts/application.html.erb'

```
    <!--    Debug applies only to 'development' environment -->
            <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? -%>
    <!--    as determined by "if Rails.env.development?"    -->
```

This leads me to believe that I am still running the application in development mode.

2) For those that have already asked questions about the signin_path problem, I still cannot see a solution that fixes it for me. I am able to sign up users, then automatically redirect them to their profile space. However, the navigation menu does not change accordingly:

```
<nav class="round">
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path -%></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Support", support_path -%></li>
      <% if signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path -%></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user -%></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) -%></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete -%></li>
      <% else %>
        <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path -%></li>
      <% end %>
```

Here is the code from the 'app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb' file:

```
    def current_user # GET current_user
        @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
    end

    def signed_in?
        !self.current_user.nil?
    end
    .
    .
    .
    private

        def user_from_remember_token
            User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
        end

        def remember_token
            cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
        end
```

Any help with this is most welcome. I am currently trying to host my application Heroku, but not getting the support I need unfortunately.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

check the [link](http://sivagollapallidotnet.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/heroku-staging-for-your-rails-app/) if the question is related to heroku server . And if you want to run on local , `rails s -p3001 -e production` may work

Comment: this has helped narrow down the problem to a 500 error, just like my live application, whereby the file 'public/500.html' is activated (when I run locally from 127.0.0.1:3001 as opposed to port 3000).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your signed_in? helper returns not what you want. So at first debug what signed_in? returns like this:

```
<%= signed_in? %>
```

or you can raise error with signed_in? as a message.

Also it seems like you forget current_user setter method, which should be called after session is created. You need to have three methods like these:

```
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end

  def user_signed_in?
    !!current_user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
    session[:user_id] = if @current_user ? current_user.id : nil
  end
```

I recommend you to move this methods to ApplicationController as protected methods.

And one last advice:

```
!self.current_user.nil?
```

looks really bad. Try to avoid using bang!, this should work for you:

```
self.current_user
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the debug tip and it returns a blank string. My code: `<p>signed_in? returns: "<%= signed_in? -%>"</p>` generates `<p>signed_in? returns: ""</p>`